# Chamada de classe sem sucesso

Tags: android, classes

Já fiz praticamente da mesma maneira, mudando só os nomes das variáveis em outro arquivo do mesmo projeto. Contudo, ao chegar na linha para chamar a classe a aplicação para e dá erro.

Abaixo a parte em que acerto as variáveis e chamo a classe:

```
 //IMEI de teste
      IMEI = "005298741256897";

      String licenca_final = (IMEI.substring(0, 4) + "-" + IMEI.substring(4, 8) + "-" + IMEI.substring(8, 12) + "-" + String.format("%4s", IMEI.substring(12, 15)).replace(' ', '0')).toUpperCase();

        //Pega o que o IMEI e insere no array de String cod2     
         String[] cod2 = new String[licenca_final.length()];

      for (int i = 0; i < licenca_final.length(); i++) {
             cod2[i] = (licenca_final.substring(i,i+1));
            }

      ClasGenerateRegCod instancia = new ClasGenerateRegCod();

      String resposta = null;
    try {
        resposta = instancia.GenerateRegCod(cod2, "PRINCIPIODACORRESPONDENCIA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      licenca.setText(resposta);
```

E abaixo os erros que apareceram no LOGCAT:

`05-27 13:37:19.682: D/AndroidRuntime(1967): Shutting down VM
05-27 13:37:19.682: W/dalvikvm(1967): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ac5ba8)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): Process: com.example.minhaslicencasnobre, PID: 1967
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.minhaslicencasnobre/com.example.minhaslicencasnobre.Verificacao}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=46; index=46
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=46; index=46
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.example.minhaslicencasnobre.ClasGenerateRegCod.GenerateRegCod(ClasGenerateRegCod.java:101)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.example.minhaslicencasnobre.Verificacao.onCreate(Verificacao.java:97)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967):     ... 11 more`

Não consegui identificar o que está errado sendo que no outro arquivo que também chamei a classe deu certo, sua diferença é na saída do retorno que eu não formatei para mostrar e a inserção de um `if` para verificação de código errado que se for verdadeiro mostra uma mensagem, senão mostra o código retornado na formato `####-####-####-####`; segue abaixo:

```
        `//Pega o que o usuário digitou e insere no array de String cod2     
         String[] cod2 = new String[cod.getText().toString().length()];

         for (int i = 0; i < cod.getText().toString().length(); i++) {
             cod2[i] = (cod.getText().toString().substring(i,i+1));
            }   

            //Chama a classe GenerateRegCod para executar o algoritmo de criptografia
            try {
                ClasGenerateRegCod instancia = new ClasGenerateRegCod();
                String m = instancia.GenerateRegCod(cod2,"PRINCIPIODACORRESPONDENCIA"); 
                if(m==""){//Se o código for diferente de 16 caracteres a classe retornará vazio e então o código é dado como inválido
                    //Mostra mensagem: código inválido
                    AlertDialog alerta;
                    //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    //define o titulo
                    builder.setTitle("Erro");
                    //define a mensagem
                    builder.setMessage("Código inválido.");
                    //define um botão como positivo
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {          
                           //conteudo do botão
                            cod.setText("");
                        }
                    });
                    //cria o AlertDialog
                    alerta = builder.create();
                    //Exibe
                    alerta.show();
                }else{//Se o código não for inválido
                //Insere o código retornado da classe em 4 grupos de 4 caracteres separados por '-' na variável finale
                finale = m.substring(0,4) + "-" + m.substring(4,8) + "-" + m.substring(8, 12) + "-" + m.substring(12);
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): 
 Caused by:java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=46; index=46
05-27 13:37:20.362: E/AndroidRuntime(1967): at
 com.example.minhaslicencasnobre.ClasGenerateRegCod.GenerateRegCod(ClasGenerateRegCod.java:101)
```

O erro é de index fora da faixa de indices de algum array dentro de GenerateRegCod (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException).